# SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'createClient' is not found

Tags: javascript, supabase

I am trying to initialise Supabase

This is my code

```
import { createClient } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabase = createClient(link,key)
```

```
<script defer src="js/signup.js" type="module"></script>
```

---

This is the following error

> SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'createClient' is not found.

Comment: Note that `defer` is superfluous on `<script type="module">`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do I do then? How do I create the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file is a UMD script, not a native JavaScript module. According to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supabase/supabase-js), the native JavaScript ("ESM") module file is `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js/+esm`:

```html
<script type="module">
import { createClient} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js/+esm";
// Check we got the function:
console.log(typeof createClient); // "function"
</script>
```

If you had to use the UMD version, again according to [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supabase/supabase-js), you'd do it like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@supabase/supabase-js"></script>
<script>
const { createClient } = supabase;
// Check we got the function:
console.log(typeof createClient); // "function"
</script>
```